# Filter out google cloud testing data from Firebase Analytics dashboard

Tags: android, google-console-developer, firebase-analytics

I'm wondering if there is a way to filter out all the analytics data coming from google cloud testing in the Firebase dashboard. I think is very important especially if we release a lot of beta version through google cloud testing (developer console).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a specific versionName for the build you send to cloud testing, you can use the app version filter in either the audience builder or in the report Filter control to filter out the cloud test data.